# Vertical-center text next to image only if short text

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, variable-length

I'd like to vertically align a text next to an image. The text can be short or long – and with responsivity in mind, the parent container can also shrink.

But I personally find that the image should *not* be centered next to **long text**. That doesn't look good.

This is a mockup of what I want.

```css
.parent {
    display: block;
    background-color: tan;
    width: 300px;
}

.parent + .parent {
    margin-top: 0.25rem;
}

.text {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
}

.image {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
}


.parent.a .image {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.parent.b .image,
.parent.c .image {
    vertical-align: top;
}

.parent.b .text {
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent a">
    <img class="image" src="https://placekitten.com/100/100/" />
    <span class="text">You are sweet</span>
</div>
<div class="parent b">
    <img class="image" src="https://placekitten.com/100/100/" />
    <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dogs are cute and cats are great</span>
</div>
<div class="parent c">
    <img class="image" src="https://placekitten.com/100/100/" />
    <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent accumsan ex elit, sed congue tortor ullamcorper et. Mauris ante diam, fermentum at ultrices sit amet, dapibus id libero. Phasellus aliquam arcu sed elit pulvinar rutrum. Nam in sem faucibus, aliquam augue ac, posuere massa.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. There is no such thing as a closing `</img>`  Remove that.

Comment: Right you are. I've overlooked that detail-

Comment: Note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Comment: Might be the case but many documentations use it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: The reason that is there due to their use of Prettier and the MDN people are stuck with it and hate the fact that the slash is auto inserted. https://github.com/orgs/mdn/discussions/242 Your link is to MDN. My link is to the actual standard. Follow the standard, Luke. The closing slash has no meaning, it does nothing, and browsers ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked into flexbox … All the `align-items` options didn't satisfy me, but you can still achieve it with `margin-top/bottom: auto` on the text element.

```css
.parent {
    display: inline-flex;
}

.text {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/woodrowshigeru/pen/MWxYKpw)

Comment: Add another ‹div› around `.image` and `.text` if the parents are aligned in grid columns and if the height of the sibling parents affect each other stretchingly.